# Silverlight combobox not displaying the bound items`

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding

I have a `ComboBox` whose `ItemSource` is bound to a list of strings (idealy i would use an Enum), this is done using the MVVM pattern.

Now i want to bind an object to the `ComboBox`, it's called `SelectedUser` and i want to bind its property: `UserType`, which is a string.

So i have got this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Usertypes}"  SelectedValue="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=SelectedUser.UserType}" />
```

It works and it does change the value of the selected user if i play with it, but the problem is, that it does not display anything in the `ComboBox` unless i select a user, and then change the `ComboBox` selection, then it works, but only for that user.

I tried playing around with `DisplayMemberPath`, `SelectedValuePath` and `SelectedItem`,
when i added those the `ComboBox` did not show anything in it (there were still options to select from, but they were invisible or something).

So what should i do? Is this a bug?
I have to mention that i have got another `ComboBox` that has a list of ints, and it works fine.

**Update:**

I was informed that I'm getting this issue because the string I'm comparing to the string in the comboBox, are not actually the same.

My string comes from the Entity Framework via Ria Services. (User.UserType)
And when it compares it to the list of strings in the ComboBox ItemSource, they are not equal, for some strange reason.

And i also heard, i might have to override Equal method for that check.
but I'm not sure where and how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Is the view notified if the `SelectedUser` changes? I could imagine that this might be the problem; if there is no such notification the `ComboBox` will not reload the `SelectedValue` if another user is selected, it will only update the binding if you make changes yourself.

If that is not it, you also need to consider that no selected value will be displayed unless the current value exactly matches one of values in the source list.

Comment: Yes, the SelectedUser implements INotifyPropertyChanged. And as i've mentioned, the other ComboBox (and TextBoxes) works fine.

Comment: I have added another caveat to my answer, besides that i cannot imagine what might be wrong right now...

Comment: That's also what i'm thinking.
but if i change and save the values, and reload the application, again it doesn't display the items at first. so i'm not sure that's it.

Comment: Well, then i am quite out of ideas. Maybe you could provide more code so people can try to reproduce it?